# Cannot read property 'style' of null even if I added position: absolute;

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fairly new to coding. I am trying to learn HTML, CSS, and Javascript by just making a racing game in the browser. I have made the functions for the controls of the car but these error messages return every time I press a button:

```
Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

This is my code

```
var car = document.getElementById('car');
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');


var carLeft = 0;

function anim(e) {
  if (e.keyCode==87) {
    //W

  }

    if (e.keyCode==65) {
      //A
      carLeft+=2;
      car.style.left = carLeft + 'px';
  }

    if (e.keyCode==83) {
      //S

  }

    if (e.keyCode==68) {
      //D
      carLeft-=2;
      car.style.left = carLeft + 'px';
  }
}

document.onkeydown =anim;
```

This is my css

```
#car {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

car variable is a collection of objects with "container" class name.

```
var car = document.getElementById('car');
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];//use this way


var carLeft = 0;

function anim(e) {
  if (e.keyCode==87) {
    //W

  }

    if (e.keyCode==65) {
      //A
      carLeft+=2;
      car.style.left = carLeft + 'px';
  }

    if (e.keyCode==83) {
      //S

  }

    if (e.keyCode==68) {
      //D
      carLeft-=2;
      car.style.left = carLeft + 'px';
  }
}

document.onkeydown = anim;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using querySelector would be a better option which would resolve the issues your are having

```js
var car = document.querySelector('#car');
var container = document.querySelector('.container');


var carLeft = 0;

function anim(e) {
  if (e.keyCode==87) {
    //W

  }

    if (e.keyCode==65) {
      //A
      carLeft+=2;
      car.style.left = carLeft + 'px';
  }

    if (e.keyCode==83) {
      //S

  }

    if (e.keyCode==68) {
      //D
      carLeft-=2;
      car.style.left = carLeft + 'px';
  }
}

document.onkeydown = anim;
```

```css
#car {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p id="car">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

**It would really be helpful if you could provide your html version too and also let me know if the answer helped or not so that I could improve it for you.**